# Reduce comma separated str in df if all strs identical

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, if-statement, lambda, apply

This is my code so far

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO("""
"name1","hej","7aa","a"
"name1","du","71al","a"
"name1","aj","74a","a"
"name1","oj","7aj","a"
"name2","fin","7ag","a"
"name2","katt","7a","a"
""")
df = pd.read_csv(data, header=0, names=["name","text2","text","as"])
df[['text2','text','as']] = df.groupby(['name']).transform(lambda 
x: ','.join(x))
df = df[['name','text','text2','as']].drop_duplicates()
df
```

Gets me most of the way.

```
df
    name          text     text2     as
0  name1  71al,74a,7aj  du,aj,oj  a,a,a
3  name2        7ag,7a  fin,katt    a,a
```

I just need one line to check each of the cols ['text','text2','as'] and if all comma separated elements are identical return just the first one

so the result I'm after is

```
df
    name          text     text2     as
0  name1  71al,74a,7aj  du,aj,oj    a
3  name2        7ag,7a  fin,katt    a
```

I've tried apply with split(','). Can't get it to work.

I am adding this post the first comments. I failed to describe my problem properly

If my df is this:

```
df
    name          text     text2     as
0  name1  71al,74a,7aj  du,aj,oj  a,b,a
3  name2        7ag,7a  fin,katt    a,a
```

I need to modify it to:

```
df
    name          text     text2     as
0  name1  71al,74a,7aj  du,aj,oj  a,b,a
3  name2        7ag,7a  fin,katt    a
```

not:

```
df
    name          text     text2     as
0  name1  71al,74a,7aj  du,aj,oj  a,b
3  name2        7ag,7a  fin,katt    a
```

Thanks

This is my final solution:

```
data = StringIO("""
"name1","hej","7aa","a"
"name1","du","71al","b"
"name1","aj","74a","a"
"name1","oj","7aj","a"
"name2","fin","7ag","a"
"name2","katt","7a","a"
""")
df = pd.read_csv(data, header=0, names=["name","text2","text","as"])
df[['text2','text','as']] = df.groupby(['name']).transform(lambda x: ','.join(x))
df = df[['name','text','text2','as']].drop_duplicates()
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].str.split(',').map(lambda x: ','.join(set(x) if len(set(x)) == 1 else x))
df
```

I had to resort to iteration. I could not get the desired results with agg. Further if someone could explain to me how len(set(x)) == 1 here, that would be much appreciated (should it be at least 2 due to the comma?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
df['as'] = df['as'].str.split(',').map(lambda x: ','.join(set(x) if len(set(x)) == 1 else x))
```

Comment: If add `set` like my solution, not necessary again split and join

Comment: Looks good. I don't understand it though! How does map work like that?

Comment: Apply's a function to each row of a series. @LiamMcIntyre

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with custom lambda function with `if-else`:

```
df = (df.groupby('name')
        .agg(lambda x: ','.join(set(x) if len(set(x)) == 1 else x))
        .reset_index())
print (df)
    name     text2          text     as
0  name1  du,aj,oj  71al,74a,7aj  a,b,a
1  name2  fin,katt        7ag,7a      a
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats nice. Unfortunately I can only colapse if ALL the elements are identical. Using a set will reduce if just some are identical.

Comment: @LiamMcIntyre - Can you change data sample for see problem?

Comment: Perfect, many thanks. You seem like an absolute wizard. Do you do any learning materials?

Comment: @LiamMcIntyre - I found nice blog this week, I hope help [link](https://www.dataschool.io/)

Comment: @LiamMcIntyre - I see answer was reaacepting, also see your solution in question. Can you explain more `I could not get the desired results with agg` ?

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it did not work. I'm not sure how you got the result you did but it did not work for me. So I used the other solution (ended up making that a function and using it with apply so no iteration). I really appreciate your help, I just couldn't get it to work for some reason

Comment: @LiamMcIntyre - Yop, i am curious, because use more complicated solution...